# Integrating a for loop into an if statement

Tags: python, for-loop

This is kind of a double-barreled question, but it's got me puzzled. I currently have the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import math

function = int(raw_input("Type function no.: "))


if function == 1:
    a = float(raw_input ("Enter average speed: "))
    b = float(raw_input ("Enter length of path: "))
    answer= float(b)/a
    print "Answer=", float(answer),

elif function == 2:
    mass_kg = int(input("What is your mass in kilograms?" ))
    mass_stone = mass_kg * 2.2 / 14
    print "You weigh", mass_stone, "stone."

else: print "Please enter a function number."
```

Now, I'd like to have some kind of loop (I'm guessing it's a for loop, but I'm not entirely sure) so that after a function has been completed, it'll return to the top, so the user can enter a new function number and do a different equation. How would I do this? I've been trying to think of ways for the past half hour, but nothing's come up.

Try to ignore any messiness in the code... It needs some cleaning up.

Comment: Have you tried just using `while True:` and letting the user hit `ctrl-c` when finished?

Comment: @kojiro Or there could be a break if function == 3 or whatever

Comment: @kojiro I like keeping things automatic. :p

Comment: Note that under `function == 1`, `a` and `b` are both already floats, so there's no need for further conversion to floats in `answer=b/a` and `print "Answer=", answer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use a `while`-loop to control the repetition, rather than a `for`-loop. This way the users aren't limited to a fixed number of repeats, *they can continue as long as they want*. In order to quit, users enter a value <= 0.

```
from __future__ import division
import math

function = int(raw_input("Type function no.: "))

while function > 0:
    if function == 1:
        a = float(raw_input ("Enter average speed: "))
        b = float(raw_input ("Enter length of path: "))
        answer = b/a
        print "Answer=", float(answer),
    elif function == 2:
        mass_kg = int(input("What is your mass in kilograms?" ))
        mass_stone = mass_kg * 2.2 / 14
        print "You weigh", mass_stone, "stone."

    print 'Enter a value <= 0 for function number to quit.'
    function = int(raw_input("Type function no.: "))
```

You can tweak this (e.g., the termination condition) as needed. For instance you could specify that 0 be the only termination value etc.

***An alternative*** is a loop that runs "forever", and break if a specific function number is provided (in this example `0`). Here's a skeleton/sketch of this approach:

```
    function = int(raw_input("Type function no.: "))

    while True:
       if function == 1:
          ...
       elif function == 2:
          ...
       elif function == 0:
          break      # terminate the loop.

      print 'Enter 0 for function number to quit.'
      function = int(raw_input("Type function no.: "))
```

*Note*: A `for`-loop is most appropriate if you are **iterating a known/fixed number of times**, for instance over a sequence (like a list), or if you want to limit the repeats in some way. In order to give your users more flexibility a `while`-loop is a better approach here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'll look into the while. Thanks for the skeleton. :)

Comment: @Downvoter .. A downvote ***without*** explanation is not useful to *anyone* (OP, SO, or me) .. the code was tested and meets OPs requirements. If not, I am happy to correct errors or improve my answer but that requires some *constructive* feedback.

Comment: There's a slight DRY violation w.r.t. `raw_input` here.  I tend to prefer the `while True/input/break` pattern to avoid this.

Comment: @DSM I am not familiar with the DRY term .. I too prefer the 2nd approach myself, but wanted to provide OP first with a solution for their original code.

Comment: @Levon: "don't repeat yourself".  If you use "while True" and put the `function = int(etc)` line at the start followed by the break, you don't have two copies of the `function = int(etc)`.

Comment: @DSM Thanks .. got it, basically avoiding redundant code, good advice. I went off googling for "DRY and software" after your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to wrap your entire script inside a loop, for example:

```
from __future__ import division
import math

for _ in range(10):

    function = int(raw_input("Type function no.: "))


    if function == 1:
        a = float(raw_input ("Enter average speed: "))
        b = float(raw_input ("Enter length of path: "))
        answer= float(b)/a
        print "Answer=", float(answer),

    elif function == 2:
        mass_kg = int(input("What is your mass in kilograms?" ))
        mass_stone = mass_kg * 2.2 / 14
        print "You weigh", mass_stone, "stone."

    else: print "Please enter a function number."
```

This will run your if statement 10 times in a row.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try this:

```
while True:
    function = ...
    if function == 0:
        break
    elif ...
```